# Prevent OpenRemoteBaseKey from hanging script powershell

Tags: powershell, registry, remote-access

I have a script that queries the registry when a computer is online but certain computers hang the script.  How can I set a timeout or an interrupt on issues with remote registry query using the following command:
For the record Try Catch does not work on this.

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $PCNAME)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could be the computer with `$PCNAME` is off-line. Did you test this first with `if ((Test-Connection -ComputerName $PCNAME -Count 1 -Quiet)) {...}`?

Comment: Unfortunately `OpenRemoteBaseKey(..)` doesnt have a timeout argument but you could for example try to open the reg key in a threadjob then wait for it and kill the thread if its above the timeout

Comment: Yes,  Computer is online.  However, mstsc hangs.  and etsn times out also.

Comment: Then there is definitely something bad happening with that computer network-wise..

Answer (score 1):

You could run it in parallel, so PowerShell (it must be executed in PowerShell 7) won't stop running through the object because one execution is stuck.

Maybe something like this:

```
foreach -parallel ($PCNAME in $listPCNAME) {
      [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $PCNAME)
}
```